# Mac asking for username and password on starting up

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, high-sierra, startup, password

I am running MacOS High Sierra on a Macbook air and this is the screen that usually comes up on booting.
[image]
The mac starts up after typing the right password. From yesterday after restarting, after typing the password on this screen, a new screen comes up asking for a username and password.
This is new and has never happened before. The unusual screen looks like this
[image]
I have tried the username and password used in the previous screenshot but that doesnt seem to work. The wallpaper that comes up is mine hence I don't suspect a hard drive crash.
Any solutions for this problem? How to go about this?

Comment: Are you using iCloud?  Do you have an account on Apple.com?  If so you might try that password.

Comment: Is this Mac enrolled into some sort of group policy e.g. at a workplace or the like?

Comment: @fluffy no. This just turned up suddenly

Answer (score 2):

I just had this problem and figured it out! I couldn’t remember my admin name, but I knew my password. Do the following:

1. Shut your computer down
2. Turn on and when you hear the chime, hold <kbd>⌥ Option</kbd> <kbd>R</kbd> together until you hear the chime a second time. This will start your computer in Recovery.
3. Select the language and what not, then you’re directed to the recovery menu with options Time Machine, Reinstall, Safari, and Disk.
4. Go to the top menu bar and select the Terminal option in the Utilities drop down.
5. Type: `resetpassword` and hit <kbd>⏎ Return</kbd>. A new window will pop up and ask for your admin login. When that pops up, it will show you your name.
6. Select the Apple logo at the top menu bar, restart, and enter that name you found plus your password.

Answer (score 1):

Go to *System Prefs → Users & Groups* and make sure the *Display login window as: list of users* is set as shown below in the *Login Option* tab on the bottom left.

[image: Login options]

Comment: I also have the same problem as the op. The issue is that we are unable to log into the computer to even access system preferences

Comment: @Polisetty Try starting it in Safe mode and repair the disk.

Comment: I've tried repairing the disk (first aid) but that doesn't seem to work. On saf mode, I erased the disk and used my backup instead. Finally that worked out

Answer (score 0):

If you remember the name that Mac shows, every time in admin access window (while unlocking any settings or installing any App). You need to enter that same username and password. Once logged in, immediately changes the setting as said by @user14492.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same issue and found what my “Name” was by using my phone to look up the devices associated with my Apple ID. Might be something like ____’s MacBook Pro. My password was still my password.